# vscode 「エラー: メイン・クラスMainのロード中にLinkageErrorが発生しました」　について

Tags: java, vscode

プログラミング初心者です。
vscodeにてコードを記述しF5キーでデバックしたところデバックコンソールに以下のエラーが発生しました。

エラー: メイン・クラスMainのロード中にLinkageErrorが発生しました

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for Main (class file version 56.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

コード内容です。

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
      System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

ついさっきまで普通にできていたのにも関わらず、突然おきました。
試したことはvscodeを再インストールしJDKも最新の12をインストールしなおしましたが問題が解決しません。

言語はjavaです。
OSはWindows10です。
JDKは12です.

どなたかご回答くださる方おりましたらよろしくお願いいたします。
問題の画像とlaunch.jsonの画像です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/182597

Comment: JDKの入手元も明記したほうが良いかなと感じました。クラスファイルバージョン `56.65535` は JDK12のpreview版のものだそうなので、JDK12がリリースされた今、使用すべきバージョンではないと思います。

Comment: ご返答していただきましてありがとうござます。JDKはこちらからインストールさせていただきました。oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/…　　　Windows 158.49 MB jdk-12_windows-x64_bin.exe – その後、JDk11.02をインストールしてみましたが駄目でした。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、[これ](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/553)だと思います。launch.jsonを開いて、`vmArgs`に`--enable-preview`を指定してみて下さい。

【参考】
[Debugging Java in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging)

Comment: ご返答していただきましてありがとうございます。launch.json内に"vmArgs": "--enable-preview"を記入してみましたが駄目でした。私が記載した場所が間違っているかもしれませんのでどこに記載するのか恐れ入りますがおしえていただけませんでしょうか。画像を張り付けておきました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 記載の仕方などに間違いがあったのかもしれませんが、画像に載っていないので何とも。teratailを見ると、ひとまず解決したようですね。

Answer (score 0):

すみませんuser32753を使っていたものです。スタックオーバフロー初心者なものでしてログインしようとしましたらなぜか32753にログインできなくなってしまい新しいアカウントを制作されてしまいました。
問題が解決いたしましたのでご報告させていただきます。visual studio codeを含め制作してきたすべてのファイルを消去しましたら治りました。何が原因でこのような問題が起こったのかにつきましては分かりませんでした。皆様お忙しい中ご協力してくださりましてありがとうございました。

Comment: アカウントが意図せず2つになってしまった場合は、ヘルプを参考に統合することを検討してください。 - [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)